# Using JSON stringify with MVC 1.0

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 1.0.

I am using JSON.Stringify() from jquery plugin Json2.js to serialize the javascript objects to send to MVC action method.

I am always getting null in the action method parameters. Am I missing something.

Does this stringify works only in MVC 3.0?? Is it possible to pass javascript objects to action methods in MVC 1.0?

Following blog I referred:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Thanks

Comment: You are confused. Whether JSON.stringify works and whether MVC will bind the result are *entirely separate issues.* You need to look at the request in Fiddler or Firebug and determine whether it's JSON.stringify or your MVC binder which is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
public void ActionMethod(string objectJson)
{
    TheClass theObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TheClass>(objectJson);

}
```

and on your page :

```
$.ajax({ url: "ActionMethod",
        data: { objectJson: JSON.stringify(theObject) }
    });
```

---

In MVC 2 (maybe it works in MVC 1) , if your class is not too complicated you can even do that :

```
public void ActionMethod(TheClass theObject)
{
}
```

+

```
$.ajax({ url: "ActionMethod",
    data: theObjectInJson
});
```

Of course the fields in theObjectInJson must match TheClass

Comment: Thanks Julien :)... It worked for me... 

I didn't try the second option... I will try that too..

Comment: Since my class is bit complicated 2nd option did work great.. It partiall y worked... 

Thanks any way... For letting me know this too.. :-)